# How can I show information from a JSON in HTML in a readable manner without knowing its structure and data?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, loops

I have a JSON but I don't know its structure (the key/value pairs that are coming in), and I need to show that info in html. I parse the string that is coming, and loop it to be able to show the info on the page in a nice manner.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
  var jsonString = '#{CertificadoBean.certificado.resumen}';
  var myObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);

  for ( var x in myObj) {
      if (myObj[x] instanceof Array) {
          document.getElementById("json").innerHTML += "&lt;p>" + "" + "&lt;b>" + x + "&lt;/b>" + ": "+JSON.stringify(myObj[x]);
      }
      else {
          document.getElementById("json").innerHTML += "&lt;p>" + "" + "&lt;b>" + x + "&lt;/b>" + ": " + myObj[x];
      }
  }
</script>
```

However in some cases it'll print out this:

```
Nivel matriculado: 10

Periodo matriculado: 2019-02

Periodos matriculados: 10

Cursos pendientes:[{"Cod.":"NIP01","Nivel":9},{"Cod.":"NI043","Nivel":10},{"Cod.":"ALE10","Nivel":10}]
```

I have a problem with displaying the info a nice manner when the loop finds an array in the json, and I'm not sure how to properly loop the array to display in a legible manner like the rest of the object.

How do I make Cursos pendientes show nicely like the others?

Comment: Can you describe how would you like to display it?

Comment: I think creating a generic way to format ANY json data you get it going to be difficult/impossible. You would have to account for any conceivable type of data for every value. If you know absolutely nothing about the data you're getting, the only "easy" solution is the answer below to use JSON.stringify.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you should use JSON.stringify in javascript.

```
var str = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2);
```

Where **obj** is your json. **null** is a replacer function ( dont use ), and **2** is a spacer ( spacing when printing )

Then you can place the stringified json on the page

```
document.body.innerHTML = str
```

See more here: [Mozilla Developer Json.stringify Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your JSON in a `<code>` or `<pre>` tag for a nice preview

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to output it as plain html you could use some recursion (and maybe for better layout some lists). By the recursion you can ensure that all the properties (in array or just plain properties) will be shown in the same way. If you intend to do this you should care about cyclic structures and think about how to handle those. Maybe you should remove cycles entirely before outputting as html.

Here is an simple example of a recursive approach with lists:

```
let object2html = function(obj) {
  if(! (obj instanceof Object))
    return obj;

  return Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
    if(obj[key] instanceof Array){
        return '<ul>' + obj[key].map(object2html).map(x => '<li>' + x + '</li>').join('') + '</ul>';
    }
    return key + ' : ' + obj[key];
  }).map(toWrap => '<p>' + toWrap + '</p>').join('');
};
```

Look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gqmLf79r/